# SQL SELECT and SUM from three

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have been cracking my head for hours on what I thought to be simple SQL SELECT command. I searched every where and read all questions related to mine. I tried an SQL Command Builder, and even read and applied complete series of SQL tutorials and manuals to try to build it from scratch understanding it (which is very important for me, regarding next commands I'll eventually have to build...).

But now I'm just stuck with the results I want, but on separates SELECT commands which I seem to be unable to get together !

Here is my case : 3 tables, first linked to the second with a common id, second linked to the third with another common id, but no common id from the first to the third. Let's say :

```
Table A : id, name
Table B : id, idA, amount
Table C : id, idB, amount
```

Several names in Table A. Several amounts in Table B. Several amounts in Table C. Result wanted : each A.id and A.name, with the corresponding SUM of B.amount, and with the corresponding SUM of C.amount. Let's say :

```
A.id
A.name
SUM(B.amount) WHERE B.idA = A.id
SUM(C.amount) WHERE C.idB = B.id for each B which B.idA = A.id
```

It's okay for "the first three columns", and "the first two columns and the fourth", both with a WHERE clause and/or a LEFT JOIN. But I can't achieve cumulating all fourth columns together without messing everything !

One could say "it's easy, just put an idA column in Table C" ! Should be easier, sure. But is it really necessary ? I don't think so, but I could be wrong ! So, I just please anyone (who I will give an eternal "SQL God" decoration) with SQL skills to answer laughing "That's so simple ! Just do that and you are gone ! Stupid little newbies..." ;)

Running VB 2010 and MS SQL Server

Thanks for reading !

Comment: So, you're trying to get a sum result set (aka one single row) back of data: A.id, A.name, sum(B.amount), sum(C.amount) and you have multiple rows related to a single A.id in B, and multiple rows related to B.id in C?

Comment: I think we could say that, yes. But just to be sure, not "one single row", but one single SUM(B.amount) and SUM(C.amount) for each (A.id and A.name).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.Id, A.Name, ISNULL(SUM(B.amount), 0) as bSum, ISNULL(SUM(C2.Amount), 0) as cSum
FROM A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.Id = B.idA
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT C.idB, SUM(C.AMOUNT) AS Amount FROM C GROUP BY C.idB) AS C2 ON C2.idB = B.Id
GROUP BY A.Id, A.Name
```

Comment: @Peter try my second example.

Comment: :) and +1'd, I tested it against my sample data... it works now.

Comment: That did the job ! I had to replace ISNULL by COALESCE because my results populates a DataGridView through a DataAdapter/DataSet, and ISNULL automatically puts checkboxes (?!) instead of values. @KlausByskovHoffmann from Spain eternally decorated "SQL God" ;) Cheers !

Comment: And one more "SQL God" decoration @NathanWheeler for your very usefull comments and adjustments !

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    a.id, 
    a.name, 
    sum(x.amount) as amountb, 
    sum(x.amountc) as amountc 
from a 
    left join (
        select
            b.id, 
            b.ida, 
            b.amount, 
            SUM(c.amount) as amountc
        from b 
        left join c 
            on b.id = c.idb
        group by 
            b.id, 
            b.amount, 
            b.ida
    ) x 
        on a.id = x.ida
group by 
    a.id, 
    a.name
```

This should give you the result set you're looking for. It sums all C.Amount's for each B.id, then adds it all together into a single result set. I tested it with a bit of sample data in MSSQL, and it works as expected.

Comment: I suppose you have tested this too, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select a.id, a.name, sum(b.amount), sum(c.amount)
from a inner join b on a.id = b.idA
inner join c on b.id = c.idB
group by a.id, a.name
```

Comment: This counts an extra B.amount for every related C.amount.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add them separately:

```
select a.id, a.name, (coalesce(b.amount, 0.0) + coalesce(c.amount, 0.0))
from a left outer join
     (select b.ida, sum(amount) as amount
      from b
      group by b.ida
     ) b
     on a.id = b.ida left outer join
     (select b.ida, sum(amount) as amount
      from c join
           b
           on c.idb = b.id
      group by b.ida
     ) c
     on a.id = c.ida
```

The outer joins are to take into account when b and c records don't both exist for a given id.

Comment: You don't have to do sub selects to outer join.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  People have strange naming conventions.  It is confusing to have two columns with the same name in different tables that refer to different things.  In any case, the point is that you need to do the summation twice, to avoid overcounting "b"s.

Comment: Ambiguous column name `amount` in your second sub-query... and I think the OP wants separate `b.amount` and `c.amount` columns, not the two columns added together.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff for giving it a try, even if I don't understand your "said" caveat ! ;)